# Emulate cordova app in browser

Tags: php, html, ios, cordova

So im building an iPad app in cordova, im getting some weird rendering issues where a 30px margin is appearing at the top of the screen when viewed on device of through xcodes ios emulator but not when i view in the browser, this is making it pretty difficult to debug as there is no functionality to view source from within the compiled cordova web viewer.

Is there a way to view a compiled cordova app in browser so i can have access to chrome developer tools. BTW Ripple emulator is not a solution all it does is view the web view in a fancy frame, it doesnt run the actual cordova app where im experiencing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to look at apps that are running in the ios simulator using Safari's inspector:

1. Open up Safari > Preferences > Advanced and check "Show Develop menu in menu bar".
2. Close out the preferences and start the iOS emulator (either from Xcode or the command line).
3. Once your app launches in the iOS emulator, go back to Safari and select Develop > iOS Simulator > index.html. You should see Safari's inspector window display.

Safari's inspector is described over here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to simulate (test) your application in the browser, simply install the new Cordova-Simulate package from NPM.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-simulate

From the command line anywhere within a Cordova project, enter:

> **simulate**

Works like a charm!   ..be sure to read the documentation on the NPM Package page!